# SQL Query to select Multiple Column from two table based on a condition

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Table_Employee`,`Table_Department` respectively, i wanted to select the manager who belongs to employee more than three times & also want to display depatment name along with it.

This task has to be done in a single query. Is it easy to do it ? 
here is my table structure .

here the Column_Empno will be the Column_Manager, which means the table is self reference

```
 Table_Employee

Column_Empno     int
Column_Fname     varchar(50)
Column_Lname     varchar(50)
Column_Job       varchar(50)
Column_Manager   int
Column_HireDate  date
Column_Salary    int
Column_Commision int
Column_DeptNo    int

 Table_Department 

Column_DeptNo    int
Column_Dname     varchar(50)
Column_Location  varchar(50)
```

Comment: Is this the real schema? A last name of `varchar(50)` sounds too wide, `Empno` is probably non-numeric, `Table_Employee` does too much:  personnel details **and** payroll (but only current state values) **and** organizational chart.

Answer (score 10):

Manager + Department:

```
SELECT Column_Fname, Column_Lname, table_Department.Column_Dname
FROM Table_Employee
INNER JOIN table_Department ON Table_Employee.Column_DeptNo = table_Department.Column_DeptNo
```

or you could also write:

```
SELECT Column_Fname, Column_Lname, table_Department.Column_Dname
FROM Table_Employee
WHERE Table_Employee.Column_DeptNo = table_Department.Column_DeptNo
```

It's not tested.
By the way, why do you Name your Colums "Column_..." and not just "Fname", "Lname",... and your table "Table_...." and not just "Employee" and "Department"?

Comment: What about the "more than three times" part of the spec?

Comment: Thank you Very Much For the fase reply  I am Very new to this SQL and its Operations

Comment: folks , Thank you Very Much For the fast reply I am Very new to this SQL and its Operations, therefore for the easy usage i have made my column and table like that. i am not able to get the answer with the above mention query.

Answer (score 7):

```
select
    t1.column_manager,
    t2.column_dname
from
(
    select column_manager, column_deptno = max(column_deptno)
    from table_employee
    group by column_manager
    having count(*) > 3
) t1
join table_department t2 on t1.column_deptno = t2.column_deptno
```